# Why isn't the value picked up in this Ruby inject call?

Tags: ruby

In the following code, if I don't add parentheses around the key, value parameters in "original.inject" (i.e., I do *original.inject({}){ |result, key, value|* ), I get a nil error as in the code comments below, as if the value is not being passed correctly.  Why is this?  What exactly is going on here?  (I'm running ruby-2.1.1)

```
def hash_test(original,options={},&block)
  original.inject({}){ |result, (key, value)|
   value = value + 2

   block.call(result, key, value)
   result
  }

end

h={:a=>3, :b=>4}

r = hash_test(h) { |result, key, value| result[key]=value }
puts r #=> {:a=>5, :b=>6}


#if no parentheses around (key, value) in original.inject, you get a:
  # hash_transformer.rb:5:in `block in hash_test': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  # from hash_transformer.rb:4:in `each'
  # from hash_transformer.rb:4:in `inject'
  # from hash_transformer.rb:4:in `hash_test'
  # from hash_transformer.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `inject` is called on a `Hash` `inject` yields the `key value` pairs as an array to the supplied block, example as below:

```
{:a=>3, :b=>4}.inject({}) do |x,y| 
  p y
  x[y[0]] = y[1]
  x
end         
#>>[:a, 3]
#>>[:b, 4]
#=> {:a=>3, :b=>4}
```

`y` yielded the first time is `[:a, 3]`, and second time is `[:b, 4]`, so you need to destructure the array by supplying the parenthesis around the arguments:

```
(a,b) = [:a, 3]
a #=> :a
b #=> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows what's going on.

**With deconstruction of hash element**

```
{:a=>3, :b=>4}.inject({}) do |x,(y,z)|
  puts "x = #{x}"
  puts "y = #{y}"
  puts "z = #{z}"
  puts
  x
end
x = {}
y = a
z = 3

x = {}
y = b
z = 4
```

**Without deconstruction of hash element**

```
{:a=>3, :b=>4}.inject({}) do |x,y,z|
  puts "x = #{x}"
  puts "y = #{y}"
  puts "z.nil? = #{z.nil?}"
  puts
  x
end
x = {}
y = [:a, 3]
z.nil? = true

x = {}
y = [:b, 4]
z.nil? = true
```

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at this post : 
http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject

It said inject is defined to take pairs parameter.

If you want to use three parameters, like (inject do |c,key,val|), then you should use parentheses to combine the (key,val)